# In a tabbed pane, make one of the panes invisible

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-8.1

How can I make invisible one of the panes in a tabbed pane?

I have one combo box and a tabbed pane. In the combo box, if I select '1' it should show only one tab; if I select '2', it should show two tabs.

How can I make it do that?

Comment: I have edited your question to make it more readable. On Stack Overflow, every user is encouraged to edit and re-edit their questions to make them as good as possible. In this, it would be useful if you could [edit] the question to show the code you're working with, what you have tried so far, and what has worked or failed so far.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: don't use a JTabbedPane. If you want to swap components, use a CardLayout. Google the tutorial for more.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically set your tab pane. write the tab pane adding code inside the combo box action code. Try to keep local variables for tabpane. If "1" is selected in `combo box` then clear the layout, add the new tab pane and re-validate. Do the same when "2" is clicked.

Other option is card layout, you can add whatever you like on top of it like in other layouts. Card Layout has a concept of "cards" which will only show when called.

Comment: Why would you manually add and remove and not use CardLayout?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Agree. I just mentioned it there. Wanted to add an answer to the user's existing way as well, so I mentioned how it can be done manually....